# Listen to if a button is disabled or enabled in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want a code that allows me to listen for any changes made on a `TextField` component for disabling or enabling a button called `save`. Is it possible to do this using bindings or something similar?

For example: `save.disableProperty().bind(...)`
I used two `TextField` components for changing the information stored in a `TableView`.
I used data binding so that when a `TableView` row is selected, the information in that row is displayed in a `TextField`.

```
@FXML
private TableView<UserData> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData, String> col1;
@FXML
private TableColumn<UserData, String> col2;
@FXML
private TextField name;
@FXML
private TextField email;

@FXML
Button newUser;
@FXML
Button save;
@FXML
Button delete;
private Connection conn;
private Statement stm;
private PreparedStatement prep;
private ResultSet result;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    populateTableView();
    configureDisable();
    table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(userDataListener);
    name.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
    email.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
    delete.disableProperty().bind(table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
    data.addListener((Change<? extends UserData> change) -> save.setDisable(false));
    name.setOnAction(ev -> email.requestFocus());
}

private final ChangeListener<UserData> userDataListener = ((v, oldV, newV) -> {
    if (oldV != null) {
        name.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.nameProperty());
        email.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldV.emailProperty());

    }
    if (newV != null) {
        name.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newV.nameProperty());
        email.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newV.emailProperty());

    }
    private void populateTableView() {
        try {
            conn = CreateConnection.getConnection();
            stm = conn.createStatement();
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            result = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select *from user");
            while (result.next()) {
                data.add(new UserData(result.getString("Name"), result.getString("Email")));
            }
            col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, String>("name"));
            col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserData, String>("email"));
            table.setItems(data);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The code can't compile because of the declaration of `populateTableView`.

Comment: @KarlRichter you have to show me the compilation error.

Comment: Your code is already not compilable. I assume it's the content of a class, but I'd put too much speculation into making it compilable.

Comment: Compilable code needs to be inside a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are using the text fields to change the data in the table (specifically here the `name` and `email` properties), and when those values in the table are changed you want to enable the save button.

You probably need listeners (rather than bindings) to do this. One way is to create an `ObservableList` from the table items that has an [extractor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-) to extract the properties of interest. When the list changes (including those properties from any list elements), set the disable property of the save button to false.

Something like:

```
    ObservableList<UserData> observableData = FXCollections.observableList(table.getItems(), 
            user -> new Observable[] {user.nameProperty(),  user.emailProperty()});
    observableData.addListener((Change<? extends Person> change) -> save.setDisable(false));
```

Comment: This answer is aimed at your particular use case; for a more general approach you might be interested in the [ReactFX framwork](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)

Comment: I changed the code by adding the following line:data.addListener((Change<? extends UserData> change) -> save.setDisable(false));. it seems to me that this line has no effect!.

Comment: Did you change the creation of `data` so that it uses an extractor (function mapping the item to an array of properties to observe), as in the code in the answer?

Comment: it is unnecessary because I am interested in all properties. However, I tried but I got the same result. but when I put this line before the loop " while (result.next()) {
                data.add(new UserData(result.getString("Name"), result.getString("Email")));
            }", it gives the desired result.

Comment: No, you need the extractor if you want the list to invalidate when the properties change. Then the listener on the list is invoked when the properties change, disabling the button. Without the extractor, the listener is only invoked when elements are added or removed from the list. The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-) are minimal but do explain what it does.

Comment: OK. Also, I would like when I cancel the change, the button becomes disable.

Comment: For that you need a lot more logic. You'll need to track the changes that were made an detect when you have reverted to the last saved state; effectively this is the same as implementing undo/redo functionality.